# Как изменить загрузочный раздел во время сборки образа Debian Live?

Tags: linux, debian, live-usb

При создании `Debian Live` образа создаётся два раздела - `iso966` с файловой системой и загрузочный `vfat`.
Binary hooks времени билда выполняются относительно `iso966`.

Как модифицировать загрузочный раздел `vfat` образа во время его сборки?

Comment: Ну а типа `mount && chroot` не работает? Раздел - это ж файл.

Comment: @donRumata `mount` можно только после сборки готового `iso`, а хочется во время

Comment: Я про mount vfat.

Comment: @donRumata разверните мысль, я пока не улавливаю

Comment: Ну я исошки не собирал, но раз на каком-то этапе у тебя появляется раздел с FAT, то его можно примонтировать и чё-нить там поделать. Собственно скорее всего он создаётся в виде файла (не `/dev/sdd`, а /home/user/deb-live-tmp/vfat.img). Вот его тогда и попробу примаунтить, чрутнуться и выполнить чё тебе надо.